# Syntax for patent number

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I propose the introduction of a syntax to indicate a patent number.

For example, a lot of posts start with something like

```
[Patent Application #20120225162](http://www.google.com/patents/us20120225162)
```

This is long and error prone. Why not replace it with a special syntax? For example,

```
[[us20120225162]]
```

Comment: I would add the country code to the patent number as well, for both consistency with the Google ID scheme and also to not restrict the site to _just_ U.S. patents, though that is clearly the current focus. (yes, I know the US vs. non-US is indicated in the [About page](http://patents.stackexchange.com/about), but it never hurts to think ahead a bit.)

Comment: @cdeszaq Done..

Comment: Was about to suggest some way of automatically detecting these. Making it easy to auto-link would be a huge step in the right direction