# Autotagging with patent number

Tags: feature-request, tags

When the question contains a link, such as

```
[Patent Application #20120225162](http://www.google.com/patents/us20120225162)
```

the system should tag it with [us20120225162](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us20120225162). This tag should be special, like a moderator tag on meta.

Edit: I don't think these tags should count towards the tag count, otherwise you run out of space very easily.

#### See Also

[Syntax for patent number](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/345)

Answer (score 2):

The automatic tagging might be fine as a suggestion but doesn't handle all cases. A question like “Is Patent A prior art for patent B” would be tagged [b](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b) [prior-art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art) but not [a](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a).

Why would the tag be special? Do you mean a distinctive color (that doesn't seem useful: the letters+numbers pattern is already visually distinctive)? Do you mean the tag should be restricted, in which case I have no idea why it would be?

Comment: Why wouldn't it get tagged with both? I meant that you shouldn't be able to delete and/or add them.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain In this example, A is not directly relevant to the question. A question tagged [tag:a] [tag:prior-art] would be looking for prior art to A. Tags should delineate the subject of a question, not subjects that get an incidental mention. I don't see why you shouldn't be able to change these tags, like any other tag.

Comment: But then only one question will ever be tagged with [tag:usaaaaa], which makes the tag redundant.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain No, there can be multiple questions addressing different claims or looking for prior art in different venues. That being said, I'm not completely convinced that the per-patent tags are useful; maybe there should be a special search for “patent mentioned in the question” instead.

Comment: I agree, that on any other SE site, we wouldn't allow such narrow tags, which is why I think they should be differentiated in some way. The only reason to keep them is for the searching capability.

Comment: What about http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/306/345? Should that be tagged with all 3 patents and 4 design patents?